# p:remoteCommand returns <eval> twice in ajax response

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I try to render a new page in a new window (or tab) with the link I get from a selected page object in an autoComplete component.
After trying multiple options the only chance in my opinion is to use javascript to catch the submit, trigger a remote command, that gives me a javascript call with the link attribute from the page object.

JSF-Snipplet (with reduced attributes in autoComplete)

```
<h:form id="autoCompleteForm">
  <p:autoComplete id="autoComplete" widgetVar="autoCompleteWidget" value="#{pageBean.selectedPage}" />
  <p:remoteCommand action="#{pageBean.showPage}" name="showPage" />
</h:form>
```

some JS:

```
// form submit
('#autoCompleteForm').on('submit', function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            showPage();
                        });
// open link
var openLink = function(pageLink) {
    window.open(pageLink, '_blank');
};
```

Bean part for action

```
public void showPage() {
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.execute("openLink('" + selectedPage.getLink() + ".xhtml')");
}
```

Everything works nice together, but the response contains the eval tag twice.

```
<partial-response>
<changes>
<update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[2851816213645347690:-2276123702509360418]]></update>
<eval><![CDATA[openLink('target.xhtml');]]></eval>
<eval><![CDATA[openLink('target.xhtml');]]></eval>
</changes>
</partial-response>
```

I tried different approaches with redirects or returning view names, but that all leads to no satisfying solutions (e.g. URL not changing or no new window).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:
I had defined `PrimePartialViewContextFactory`in my faces-config before:

```
<factory>
  <partial-view-context-factory>org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContextFactory</partial-view-context-factory>
 </factory>
```

By removing it the application acts like expected.

This also solves a problem (`JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data`) with pagination and sorting in DataTables.